# angular ui-sref inside nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I`m having trouble at the time of listing some elements inside ng-repeat directives while i attach them the ui-sref attribute. Have tried to do it using ng-click and $state.go inside controller but without success.

Btw, i`m passing params to those ui-sref directives and those params are Ok when I look at the console, but the API route is wrong.

Have searched for hours about this but cannot find an answer.

Here is my code:

```
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{tasklist.name}}</h4>
    <div class="table-responsive connectList" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-repeat="task in tasklist.tasks">
        <span class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="project-detail.taskedit({id:task.id})"> Edit </span>
        <span class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="project-detail.taskdelete({id:task.id})"> Remove </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-new-task" ui-sref="project-detail.tasknew({id:tasklist.id})">
            New Task
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the states i`m calling:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('velettaApp')
    .config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('project', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/project',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'velettaApp.project.home.title'
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/project/projects.html',
                controller: 'ProjectController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('project');
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                return $translate.refresh();
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('project-detail', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/project/{id}',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'velettaApp.project.detail.title'
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/project/project-detail.html',
                controller: 'ProjectDetailController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('project');
                return $translate.refresh();
            }],
            entity: ['$stateParams', 'Project', function($stateParams, Project) {
                return Project.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise;
            }],
            loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                    {
                        name: 'ui.sortable',
                        files: ['app/plugins/ui-sortable/sortable.js']
                    }
                ]);
            }
        }
    })
            .state('project-detail.tasklist', {
                parent: 'project-detail',
                url: '/task-list/new',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
                },
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', 'Project',function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal, Project) {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'app/entities/task-list/task-list-dialog.html',
                            controller: 'TaskListDialogController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm',
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            size: 'lg',
                            resolve: {
                                entity: function () {
                                    return {
                                        name: null,
                                        dateCreated: moment().utc().format().slice(0, -1)+'.000Z',
                                        isPrivate: null,
                                        id: null,
                                        project: Project.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise
                                    };
                                },
                                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('taskList');
                                    return $translate.refresh();
                                }]
                            }
                        }).result.then(function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail', null, {reload: true});
                        }, function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail');
                        });
                    }]
            })
            .state('project-detail.tasknew', {
                parent: 'project-detail',
                url: '/task/new',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
                },
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal','TaskList', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal, TaskList) {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'app/entities/task/task-dialog.html',
                            controller: 'TaskDialogController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm',
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            size: 'lg',
                            resolve: {
                                entity: function () {
                                    return {
                                        creatorId: null,
                                        title: null,
                                        type: null,
                                        dateCreated: moment().utc().format().slice(0, -1)+'.000Z',
                                        dateDue: null,
                                        taskStatus: null,
                                        priority: null,
                                        isCompleted: null,
                                        id: null,
                                        taskList: ['$stateParams', 'TaskList', function($stateParams, TaskList) {
                                            return TaskList.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise;
                                        }]
                                    };
                                },
                                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('task');
                                        return $translate.refresh();
                                }]
                            }
                        }).result.then(function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail', null, {reload: true});
                        }, function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail');
                        });
                    }]
            })
            .state('project-detail.taskedit', {
                parent: 'project-detail',
                url: '/task/{id}/edit',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
                },
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal','Task', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal, Task) {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'app/entities/task/task-dialog.html',
                            controller: 'TaskDialogController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm',
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            size: 'lg',
                            resolve: {
                            entity: ['Task', function(Task) {
                            return Task.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise;
                            }],
                            translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('task');
                                        return $translate.refresh();
                                }]
                            }
                        }).result.then(function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail', null, {reload: true});
                        }, function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail');
                        });
                    }]
            })
            .state('project-detail.taskdelete', {
                parent: 'project-detail',
                url: '/task/{id}/delete',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
                },
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal','Task', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal,Task) {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'app/entities/task/task-delete-dialog.html',
                            controller: 'TaskDeleteController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm',
                            size: 'md',
                            resolve: {
                                entity: ['Task', function (Task) {
                                        return Task.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
                                    }]
                            }
                        }).result.then(function () {
                            $state.go('project-detail', null, {reload: true});
                        }, function () {
                            $state.go('^');
                        });
                    }]
            })
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: where have you defined the state for  'task-list-detail'?

Comment: Sorry, that one is the only one working, is defined in another archive, removing it from sample code!

Comment: You should define all your urls as   url: '/task/:id/edit', and not  url: '/task/{id}/edit', for it to accept the params you are passing. Also your last state 'project-detail.tasknew' is not even accepting id as a param in its url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the *url* of `project-detail.taskedit`:

```
url: '/task/{id}/edit',
```

Now, its parent state, `project-detail`, *url*:

```
url: '/project/{id}', // Note the same {id} as my child 'project-detail.taskedit' state
```

On both state you have the same parameter name **id**, so you can change the url of `project-detail.taskedit` to

```
url: '/task/{taskId}/edit', // My new parameter name won't get ui-router confuse my params and my parent parameters! :)
```

And then the `ui-sref` should be:

```
ui-sref="project-detail.taskdelete({id:tasklist.id, taskId:task.id})"
```

This will make `ui-router` to be able to attach the parameter with the correct value.

Note that you should also change the `onEnter` settings of the `project-detail.taskdelete` by changing the reference `$stateParams.id` to `$stateParams.taskId` (And on any other places that should be referencing to the new *taskId* parameter).

You should make the same changes in the `'project-detail.taskedit'` state too (Replace the parameter to `taskId` and so on...)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I was missing the point that child states inherited that "id" parameter. It was driving me crazy.